# Print specified number of items in list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, printing, list-comprehension

I have a list

```
res = [6, 6, -1, -1, 6]
```

and I want to print the first v1 characters on one line separated by a space; and the remaining v2 characters on a new line separated by a space.

```
res = [6, 6, -1, -1, 6]
restemp = res
out = []
v1, v2 = 3, 2
for iii in range(v1):
    out.append(res[iii])
for abc in range(v1):
    restemp.pop(abc)
[print(ou, end=' ') for ou in out]
[print(ttv, end=' ') for ttv in restemp]
```

this returns

```
6 6 -1 6 -1
```

but I want it to return

```
6 6 -1
6 -1
```

I tried adding a `print('\n')` statement in between but then it returns

```
6 6 -1

6 -1
```

Comment: Please don't use list-comprehensions for side-effects, such as printing. Only use them for creating new lists.

Comment: So is your list `[6, 6, 6, -1, -1, 6]` or `[6, 6, -1, -1, 6]`? And why are you creating the second part in some really weird way? You're not saying anything about that. And what's up with not using `v2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left off the `end=` in your inserted statement, which means you'll use the default newline.  You need to use only one:

```
print()
```

or

```
print('\n', end='')
```

Even better, try using the `join` function: join each group into a space-separated string, and then join those with a newline:

```
out = ' '.join(str(k) for k in res[:v1])
tmp = ' '.join(str(k) for k in res[v2:])
result = '\n'.join(out, tmp)
print(result)
```

Note that you can link that into one long command ... and then don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
print(*out)
print(*restemp)
```

output:

```
6 6 -1
6 -1
```